# codeigniter overrides session data from a non-ci app

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I've two codes on the same domain. A legacy code works with a new `codeigniter` app.

Legacy code writes some data to `$_SESSION` that I need to use in codeigniter app.

If I use `session_start()` in `codeigniter` I can access to all `$_SESSION` data.

But if I use

```
$this->load->library('session');
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

all I see is

```
array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1554448209) }
```

Is there a way to use codeigniter session library and access session data from legacy code?

Answer (score 0):

### Direct answer

*-- edit start*

I realized that you need to do the opposite Legacy --> CI, my original answer was CI --> PHP. So you will have to set the session_id on CI, and I think it would be best do using the Hook `pre_controller` with something like:

```
if(session_id() != $_GET['legacy-session-id']) {
    session_destroy();
    session_id($_GET['legacy-session-id']);
    session_start();
}
```

*-- edit end*

#### CI Session Config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sess_';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 3600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

`sess_cookie_name` must be `sess_` and `sess_match_ip` must be `FALSE` if you use default PHP Session driver in legacy PHP, you probably does.

#### Pure PHP

```
if(session_id()) session_destroy();
$CI_SESSION_ID = '2gmv4p3tfb8ds0btmi1m5um9nfei5lku'; // you'll have to get somehow
session_id( $CI_SESSION_ID );
//if sess_match_ip == true
//session_id( md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . $CI_SESSION_ID );
session_save_path (sys_get_temp_dir());
session_start();

echo 'session_id = ' . session_id() . '<br />';
echo 'session_name = ' . session_name() . '<br />';
echo "session_save_path = " . session_save_path () . '<br />';
$_SESSION['my-test'] = time();
var_dump($_SESSION);

/* RESULT
session_module_name = files
session_id = f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d62gmv4p3tfb8ds0btmi1m5um9nfei5lku
session_name = PHPSESSID
session_save_path = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
D:\Projetos\sis-main\teste.php:18:
array (size=2)
  '__ci_last_regenerate' => int 1554476877
  'my-test' => int 1554477377
*/
```

#### Result on CI:

```
echo 'session_id = ' . session_id() . '<br />';
echo 'session_name = ' . session_name() . '<br />';
echo "session_save_path = " . session_save_path () . '<br />';
var_dump($_SESSION);
/*
session_module_name = user
session_id = 5a82l70ra63p9bsch3rbhac1m4ekqppo
session_name = sess_
session_save_path = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
D:\Projetos\sis-main\application\core\MY_Controller.class.php:22:
array (size=2)
  '__ci_last_regenerate' => int 1554477602
  'my-test' => int 1554477377
*/
```

### Explanation

CodeIgniter use a custom session handler. With some engineering I was able to do it.

If you look at CodeIgniter session drive you will have this:

```
//@CI_Session_files_driver::open

$this->_file_path = $this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    .$name // we'll use the session cookie name as a prefix to avoid collisions
    .($this->_config['match_ip'] ? md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) : '');
```

The `$name` variable if loaded from `$config['sess_cookie_name']`. And if you have configured to set the IP address, you'll have the MD5 on the file name. Which you does not on default PHP session driver.

So, if you have this CI config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'myproject_';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 3600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

You'll end up with this file name for session `myproject_f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d62gmv4p3tfb8ds0btmi1m5um9nfei5lku`.

That's the CI part, now let's begin with PHP part.

The default PHP session drive prepend on file name the value "sess_". So you would have something like this: `sess_ab0281624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d62`. If you open your session directory you'll see it.

Hope it helps.